# Form action targeting PHP loaded with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have loaded a PHP file into a div using jQuery. I have a form inside the PHP that needs to target itself with the results. I have used the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="shopping_cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

However, it doesn't work as it loads and jumps to the page itself, rather than where it is currently loaded in the div.

I have also tried:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

This, however, reloads the index page rather than the loaded page.

Suggestions on how to target the PHP within the DIV without navigating away from it?

Comment: Not so sure if this helps but be sure to put in an <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> to output the script name.

what is the name of your file

Answer (score 0):

you could go for a js option and post the form with jquery. But you could do it with php to by just using a anchor tag.

```
<a name="formlocation"> </a>
<form method="post" action="shopping_cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>#formlocation">
```

But I'm not 100% sure if that is what you want to do